# Term of rotation matrix entries equals 1 - proof concept?!

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, rotations

I derived some stuff and it is happening that i come to the following expression:

$\frac{r_{13}^2 + r_{23}^2}{(r_{11}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{21})^2 + (r_{12}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{22})^2}$

that must equal 1 for all first two rows of a rotation matrix (orthogonal matrix).

$$  \begin{matrix}
    r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & \\
    \end{matrix}   $$
$$  \begin{matrix}
 r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & \\
    \end{matrix}   $$

I am confused how to proof this! I see a bit of a cross product in the denominator but can't identify the relation combined with the numerator.

Comment: I tested this by generating random $3\times3$ orthogonal matrices, and it certainly seems to be true, but I don't know why.

Comment: I did the same and come to the same conclusion. Writing it as $(r_{11}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{21})^2 + (r_{12}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{22})^2 = r_{13}^2 + r_{23}^2 $ shows that the sums are equal but not the summands. And I don't know why as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this just by using the facts that the rows and columns have length one and are mutually orthogonal.

$$\begin{align}
&(r_{11}r_{23}-r_{13}r_{21})^2+(r_{12}r_{23}-r_{13}r_{22})^2\\
&=r_{11}^2r_{23}^2+r_{13}^2r_{21}^2-2r_{11}r_{21}r_{13}r_{23}+
r_{12}^2r_{23}^2+r_{13}^2r_{22}^2-
2r_{12}r_{22}r_{13}r_{23}\\
&=r_{23}^2(r_{11}^2+r_{12}^2)+r_{13}^2(r_{21}^2+r_{22}^2)
-2r_{13}r_{23}(r_{11}r_{21}+r_{12}r_{22})\\
&=r_{23}^2(1-r_{13}^2)+r_{13}^2(1-r_{23}^2)-2r_{13}r_{23}(-r_{13}r_{23})\\
&=r_{13}^2+r_{23}^2-2r_{13}^2r_{23}^2+2r_{13}^2r_{23}^2\\
&=r_{23}^2+r_{13}^2
\end{align}$$

I see that an answer has been posted since I started typing this (I'm awfully slow), but I'm going to post it anyway, since it's a bit different.

Comment: [1] Short proof indeed.

Comment: @JeanMarie But yours is more perspicuous.  I couldn't see where the cofactors wee coming from until I read your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$ R:= \begin{pmatrix}
    r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\
 r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} \\
 r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33}
    \end{pmatrix}$$

be a rotation matrix. Knowing that $\det(R)=1$

$$R^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
+\begin{vmatrix}
r_{22}&r_{23}\\
r_{32}&r_{33}
\end{vmatrix}&-\begin{vmatrix}
r_{21}&r_{23}\\
r_{31}&r_{33}
\end{vmatrix}&+\begin{vmatrix}
r_{12}&r_{13}\\
r_{32}&r_{33}
\end{vmatrix}\\
-\begin{vmatrix}
r_{11}&r_{13}\\
r_{21}&r_{22}
\end{vmatrix}&+\begin{vmatrix}
r_{11}&r_{12}\\
r_{31}&r_{33}
\end{vmatrix}&-\begin{vmatrix}
r_{11}&r_{12}\\
r_{31}&r_{32}
\end{vmatrix}\\
+\begin{vmatrix}
r_{12}&r_{13}\\
r_{22}&r_{23}
\end{vmatrix}&-\begin{vmatrix}
r_{11}&r_{13}\\
r_{21}&r_{23}
\end{vmatrix}&+\begin{vmatrix}
r_{11}&r_{12}\\
r_{21}&r_{22}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}^T$$

(please note the transposition operator at the top).

Besides, a rotation matrix being an isometry :

$$R^{-1}=R^T\tag{0}$$

Therefore the lower right entry of $R$ can be expressed under the form :

$$r_{33}=\begin{vmatrix}
r_{11}&r_{12}\\
r_{21}&r_{22}
\end{vmatrix}\tag{*}$$

Now, let us consider the condition you give

$$r_{13}^2 + r_{23}^2=(r_{11}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{21})^2 + (r_{12}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{22})^2$$

Let us show that it can be simplified (see relationship (3)).

Indeed, as the rows of $R$ must have a unit norm, we have, for the third row :

$$r_{13}^2+r_{23}^2+r_{33}^2=1 \ \iff \ r_{13}^2+r_{23}^2=1-r_{33}^2 \tag{1}$$

In a similar way, as $R^{-1}$ is itself an isometry, its columns have as well a unit norm, we have, for the third column :

$$(r_{11}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{21})^2 + (r_{12}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{22})^2+(r_{11}r_{22} - r_{12}r_{21})^2=1$$

which implies  $$(r_{11}r_{23} - r_{13}r_{21})^2 + (r_{12}r_{23}-r_{13}r_{22})^2 = 1 - (r_{11}r_{22} - r_{12}r_{21})^2\tag{2}$$

Thus we have to prove, taking (1) and (2) into account :

$$1-r_{33}^2=1 - (r_{11}r_{22} - r_{12}r_{21})^2$$

Otherwise said, we have to establish that :

$$ \pm \ r_{33} = r_{11}r_{22} - r_{12}r_{21}\tag{3}$$

which is exactly (*).

Answer (score 1):

The denominator shows the sum of squares of two components of a cross product, which are precisely the components of the vector at the denominator.